# Extract tar file with spaces?

Tags: bash, tar, spaces

Anyone knows how to extract files with spaces?
The file I'm trying to extract is in the following format author name - file name.tar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
tar xvf "tar file.tar" "other file"
```

Comment: @HAsHpANTs Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.